# asyncio troubles & advises

Tags: python, asynchronous, cython, python-asyncio

I'm pretty new to **asyncio** and need a few advises on how to build the following scenario. I have a **Cython** extension which accepts a callback. The former is executed every time a new event arrives. However starting the mechanism which collects those events is a blocking operation, i.e. it blocks the main thread.
The Cython extension also accepts the `asyncio.Queue`, and invokes the `put_nowait` method from the callback. Now I want to setup the consumer for the queue to process the events. This could be the possible pseudo code behind the scenario:

```
aioq = asyncio.Queue(1000)    
cext = CythonExtension(aioq)

def c(aioq):
   while not aioq.empty():
      e = yield from aioq.get()
loop.create_task(c(aioq))

# i'm not sure how to run the event loop
# and keep on initializing the cython extension
# because this call also blocks...
#loop.run_forever()   

# so i tried this.

loop.run_in_executor(None, cext.start) <- this is a blocking operation
# start the event loop
loop.run_forever()
```

When I run the example, the `asyncio` queue is filled with events, but the `c` task never executes - I am not able to get any event from the queue. Would appreciate any feedback or pointers on how to address this.

Answer (score 1):

Regular Python code will allow another thread a turn after a certain number of bytecode operations have executed. See [this set of slides](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf), for example, which discusses improvements to the mechanism, but also explains the mechanism.

Cython doesn't execute bytecode so never triggers this swapping mechanism, and so the Cython thread will block indefinitely (as you've found). A simple way round it is to add the following lines to your main Cython loop in `cext.start` (so it executes regularly):

```
with nogil:
    pass
```

This releases, then immediately tries to reclaim the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), which allows other threads to execute (if another thread does execute then Cython will have to wait).

An even better option is to identify bits of your Cython code that don't requite the GIL (mainly bits that use C datatypes, rather than Python data types) and wrap those in a `with nogil:` block. This will allow your Cython code to continue doing something useful while another thread also runs.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. However, it has been a motivation to start refactoring the code in order to overcome the limitations of the GIL. I'm experimenting extremely high performance boosts.

Comment: Well, I'm glad it helped in some way, if not the way you wanted! I'm afraid I don't really understand `asyncio` well enough to help further (this answer was a bit of a guess because it's a problem that sometimes comes up in Cython). It might help someone else answer the question if you showed some simplified example code for `CythonExtension`

Comment: One other thought: does `c` execute, find an empty queue, and finish before the extension has had time to add anything to the queue? (Or am I misunderstanding?)

Comment: Here is the code for the Cython extension: https://github.com/rabbitstack/fibratus/blob/master/kstream/kstreamc.pyx. Note this version is still affected by the GIL. The code I'm testing calls the `asyncio.Queue.put_nowait` method instead of the provided Python's callback (line 313). At first I thought It could be because of finding the queue empty. Then I changed the coroutine to loop indefinitely, but I'm still not seeing any messages consumed.